# Deallocating memory used by Javascript objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, garbage-collection

Should I free the allocated memory by myself, or is there a kind of garbage collector?

Is it okay to use the following code in JavaScript?

```
function fillArray()
{
  var c = new Array;
  c.push(3);
  c.push(2);
  return c;
}

var arr = fillArray();
var d = arr.pop()
```

thanks

Comment: What would you want to do in this example?

Answer (score 8):

Quoted from the [Apple JavaScript Coding Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/ScriptingAutomation/Conceptual/JSCodingGuide/Advanced/Advanced.html):

> Use delete statements. Whenever you
>   create an object using a new
>   statement, pair it with a delete
>   statement. This ensures that all of
>   the memory associated with the object,
>   including its property name, is
>   available for garbage collection. The
>   delete statement is discussed more in
>   “Freeing Objects.”

This would suggest that you use a `delete` command to then allow the garbage collector to free the memory allocated for your `Array` when you're finished using it. The point that the `delete` statement only removes a reference is worth noting in that it differs from the behaviour in C/C++, where there is no garbage collection and `delete` immediately frees up the memory.

Comment: Just keep in mind that the "delete" operator doesn't actually 'delete' an object—it just removes a reference to the object so that JavaScript's Garbage Collector can easily see that the object is not being used anymore. For more information, see the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742623/deleting-objects-in-javascript.

Comment: The `delete` operator removes a property from an object, so does not work on variables. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Answer (score 3):

The variables `arr` and `d` will exist as global variables and will exist until they are collected by the Garbage Collector.

The variables will be set as properties on the global object i.e. `window` in a browser environment but since they are declared with `var`, [they will not be deletable from the global object.](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete)

In your particular case, the best course of action might be to assign `null` to the variables after you are finished with them. You may also want to consider containing their scope to a function and do what you need to do with them inside that function.

Comment: This is wrong. The variables `arr` and `d` are not properties of an object, they are variables, so they cannot be 'deleted' using the `delete` keyword. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Comment: I suggest assigning them to something else. `arr = null; d = null;`

Comment: @AlexJM Probably fell into this trap - http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/#firebug_confusion. Happy to update the answer and thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 3):

Memory management in JavaScript is automatic and there is a garbage collector (GC).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management

You cannot explicitly delete the variables `d` and `arr`, but you can remove references to their value by setting the variables to something else, such as `null`, to allow the GC to remove them from memory.

```
arr = null;
d = null;
```

Note that the `delete` keyword only deletes object properties.