# JavaScript DELETE statement. Query

Tags: javascript

I was just wondering if the DELETE statement is supported by all browsers e.g:

```
delete myObj;
```

I just want to make 100% sure if all browsers support this or not?
Also is there any browser or maybe mobile (cell) phones that do not?

Comment: Not all browsers support Javascript, so no.

Comment: `delete` is used to remove properties from objects (ie `delete foo.bar`, `delete foo[42]`, ...); strict-mode ES5 will even throw an `SyntaxError` if you incorrectly use it on local variables...

Comment: @MarkByers Not all computers have mice. That doesn't mean I shouldn't write GUI's. I think it time for use to accept that the 'scriptless' web is deprecated, and not worth our design consideration any more the IE7 or the Netscape browser are.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Mozilla's Developer Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/delete_Operator) provides the following information:

```
Implemented in: JavaScript 1.2, NES3.0
ECMA Version:   ECMA-262
```

So you can check your target browser against this for an idea of whether it's supported at all or not.

*[Extreme testing of JavaScript delete operator on different browsers](http://trilancer.wordpress.com/2009/06/10/extreme-testing-of-javascript-delete-operator-on-different-browsers/)* seems to suggest that nearly all major browsers do support it, just not equally well. Furthermore, the author provides an *extreme* test page for you to experiment with your browser online at http://www.trilancer.com/extreme_delete.html

I would also consider reading the following question for more details on how to property use the `delete` operator:

- [Deleting Objects in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742623/deleting-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: Although this is slightly off topic... it seems that it just tests the browsers speed or performance... however it does explain a lot about the delete so thanks

Comment: @Val, I've since updated this solution to explain when it was introduced, how to use it, and how well it works in various browsers.

Comment: @Jonathan I have noticed... thank you btw you have given more information than i would of thought i was going to get :)

Comment: Unfortunately `http://www.trilancer.com/extreme_delete.html` is now a dead link `)-:` Looking for it in other locations ...

Comment: @JonathanSampson is the word `property` a typo? (near the end of last line).

Answer (score 5):

To directly answer your question, as far as I am aware, any browser that supports JavaScript supports `delete`.  I checked and it existed in the specification for [ECMAScript 1](http://www.mozilla.org/js/language/E262.pdf) (released in 1997) so it's been around for a while now.