# How to clear a object from memory using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deleting Objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742623/deleting-objects-in-javascript)

This is the demo code:

```
function a(){
    this.a='aaa'
}
var aa=new a
```

How to clear the `aa` object from the memory?

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong but I think setting the variable to `null` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

set `aa = null`, alert(aa)!