# Is this memory leak?? In javascript

Tags: javascript, performance

```
(function () {

    //create object with two initail properties
    var obj = {};
    obj.a = { a1: 1, a2: 2 };
    obj.b = { b1: 1, b2: 2 };

    //create a new property 'c' and refer property 'a' to it
    obj.c = obj.a;

    //cyclic reference
    obj.a = obj.b;
    obj.b = obj.a;



    //this function removes a property from the object
    // and display all the three properties on console, before and after.
    window.showremoveshow = function () {

        console.log(obj.a, '-----------a');
        console.log(obj.b, '-----------b');
        console.log(obj.c, '-----------c');

        //delete proprty 'a'
        delete obj.a;

        //comes undefined
        console.log(obj.a, '-----------a'); 

        //displays b
        console.log(obj.b, '-----------b'); 

        //still displays the initial value obj.a
        console.log(obj.c, '-----------c'); 
    }

})();
```

Now:  After deleting obj.a and checking the value of obj.c we find that 
obj.c still refers to the initial value of obj.a, however obj.a itself doesnt exist. So is this a memory leak. As obj.a is deleted and its initial value still exist.

Edit: is this means,like although we removed the property(obj.a) its values exist even after. Which can be seen in obj.c.

Comment: It is not a leak. the object doesn't 'live" in the variable, all object in javascript are references. The object gets garbage collected when the last reference to it dies, as long as you have any reference to it, it lives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete only removes the reference, so that's what happens. Complete answer also here:

[Deleting Objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742623/deleting-objects-in-javascript)

And if you have some time on your hands, check this :)

http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/

Answer (score 1):

That's not a memory leak.
obj.c only holds a copy of the value assigned to obj.a.