# Is it possible to delete the object itself, not the reference

Tags: javascript, reference

```
var a = {
    "example" : true
};

var x = [a], y = [a];

delete x[0];

console.log(y);
```

In the above code, would it be possible to have a deleted, not just the reference in x ?

Comment: What about "delete a;" ?

Comment: You want to de-reference the object `a`

Comment: If you want manual memory management, forget it. The object is deleted when the GC sees it fit and when it can prove there are no more references, not a second earlier.

Comment: What do you mean by "delete the object itself"?  What would `y` contain?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's up to the garbage collector. As long as there's some reference to the object, it will not be garbage collected.

If you want it to be cleaned up, make sure there are no more references.

So to answer your question, no, there's no way to explicitly destroy an object. If `a` and `y[0]` are still referencing it, you can't do it from your `x` variable.

To be clear, `x[0]` is not referencing `a`. It is pointing to the same object in memory that `a` is referencing.

Comment: So, there is no way of removing a from y, without knowing the index ?

Comment: @glider: Aside from dereferencing all the items in the `y` Array, or iterating over the Array to look for it (or using `.indexOf()` if supported), then not really.

Answer (score 1):

i think you should refer this question.

[Deleting Objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742623/deleting-objects-in-javascript)