# destroying an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

This I know is quite a basic one, but, please tell me how can I destroy an object in javascript, that is created dynamically.

Actually I have created an instance of nicEdit javascript text editor, and after taking user's input in it and saving the entered text, I want to destroy it.

Here's a snippet of code im using to create an instance:

```
    myNicEditor = new nicEditor();
```

Here nicEdit variable is global.

And here's how im destroying it right now:

```
    myNicEditor = undefined;
```

inside a function. But, its not deleting. I know this b'coz when i create another instance using same variable name, i'm able to see my last entered text, that it has saved internally.

Plz help..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742623/deleting-objects-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the [documentation](http://nicedit.com/demos.php?demo=3), it is stated clearly.

Comment: Also, @dm03514 ur link gave a lot of useful info :)

Comment: Thnx @mu is too short ... it helpd :)