# How can I delete a jQuery event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have this:

```
function test()
{
    this.method = function ()
                {
                    $("html").mousemove(function(event) {
                        console.log('~> moved');
                    });
                }
    this.method();
}

testInstance = new test();

testInstance = null;  // delete window.testInstace;
```

Although I have removed references to the object by setting `testInstance` to null (I've also tried deleting it as a property of `window`), the mousemove event handler continues to operate and write to the console. If deleting the object that established the event handler doesn't remove it what then should I do to remove the event handler?

Comment: You have to unbind the event handler explicitly.

Comment: Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742623/deleting-objects-in-javascript

Comment: JS doesn't have the notion of "deleting" objects.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to remove an event handler in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

if you are using jquery 1.7

```
$('html').off('mousemove');
```

else

```
$('html').unbind('mousemove');
```

Answer (score 3):

Destroying the object will not have any effect on the event handler that you've added. In order to remove the event handler, you need to [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) the event.