# JavaScript Garbage Collection Seems to Not be Running in Chrome Extension background.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am coding a Chrome extension.
I have a $.post() command that runs on a timer in the background (setInterval).
The callback invokes a parse function:

```
function parseData(new_data) {
  new_data = $.parseJSON( new_data );
  for(var x=0; x<new_data.length; x++) {
    var obj = new CustomObj( new_data[x] );
    // I commented out code here in order to help isolate the problem.
  }
}
```

CustomObj is prototyped in a typical JS manner...

```
function CustomObj(data){
   this.data = data;
}
CustomObj.prototype.getName = function() {
  return this.data.name;
}
// Of course, there are a few more methods here...
```

The problem:
The extension will cause major lag. If I set it to do the $.post() every 10s (simply to speed up the appearance of the problem), within 5 minutes refreshing any tab in Chrome will show "Waiting on [My Extension]" for about 30s. Eventually the browser will more or less lock up.

What I've discovered: if I comment out the innards of the for() loop, everything is just peachy. No lag ever. If I simply put the above line in the for(); loop (creating the CustomObj), the problem returns.

It seems like a garbage collection problem, as far as I can tell. I've tried implicitly defining the obj variable as well as explicitly deleting it (though [Deleting Objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742623/deleting-objects-in-javascript) makes me believe that delete is insufficient ). Nothing seems to work.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know, maybe the reuse of new_data is causing problems? Or is it that you're looping through a JSON object? Chrome's heap profiler (https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/heap-profiling) would probably help.

Comment: (Wait, aren't you that person who wrote Start Google Plus?...nevermind)