# Javascript GC and assigning objects to null

Tags: javascript, memory-management, garbage-collection

Say I instantiate a large object with `var` and `new`. After I'm done with it, can I "free" it by setting it to `null`? Is this something Javascript GCs look for?

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/742666/1249581.

Comment: Just try to limit its scope by as much as possible and use `delete` if really needed.

Comment: @d_inevitable `delete` removes the reference to the object but not the object itself. However, if you remove the reference, GC will know about useless object data faster.

Comment: I know. `delete` has merely the effect of setting it to null. Therefore I said, limit the scope as much as possible.

Comment: @d_inevitable: `delete` is not meant for variables. It only removes properties from objects.

Comment: @amnotiam so delete is not officially supported for variables? I've tried this on ff and it works totally fine with variables.

Comment: @amnotiam hmm you are right, it doesn't work in chrome.

Comment: @d_inevitable: Yeah, I think there are some browser bugs that sometimes allow it, but they shouldn't. I think the only time it will work is if you set a property on the global object, then use `delete` to remove it. I believe in that case it will successfully remove the global variable as well. Not sure though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The garbage collection is interested in objects, that are not referenced by ANY other object. So make sure there are no references left anywhere in your application (Arrays etc.)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RWmzxyMf2cE That's a nice "conference" by Colt McAnlis about Javascript and GC.. It's interesting :)

Answer (score 1):

You can break the reference by setting the variable to `null`, but it doesn't break any other references.

All references need to be broken individually before the object can be GC'd.

So yes, if the only reference to the object that is held by that variable, then setting it to `null` will free it for eventual GC.

Answer (score 0):

as am not i am stated, you'll need to break all references in order for a variable to be eligible for garbage collection. This can be a difficult task if you can't track down that last reference to a specific Object, so use the tools available to you for this task. Personally I use the Chrome's Heap Profiler which you can read about [in the chrome docs](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/heap-profiling).

Also, note that only non-primitive types are passed by reference (and therefore only non-primitive types can be GC'd).