# why delete object in javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deleting Objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742623/deleting-objects-in-javascript)

I have came to the use of delete property. It isn't working. I don't know whether it is a browser compatibilty issue or not? is it a reference being not deleted?

My concepts about pointer is not that clear. Please let us know whats going wrong?

**Code:**

```
    <html>
        <script language="JavaScript">
        MyDate = new Date();
        document.write("MyDate=",MyDate,"<br>");

        delete MyDate;
        document.write("MyDate=",MyDate);   //MyDate=undefined should be output
        </script>
    </html>
```

But the **output** is only first document.write:

```
MyDate=Mon Oct 01 2012 15:27:56 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Comment: Refer existing question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742623/deleting-objects-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working . since you are deleting the `myDate`, browser is throwing an exception while you trying to access `myDate` in second `document.write` [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hu47f/1/)

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: MyDate is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, `delete` in javascript deletes properties.

Comment: Yes, this is the proper behaviour of `delete`.  However, in the browser, all global variables are properties of the `window` object and are deletable.

Comment: @AndyE, that should be `delete window.MyDate` then, I believe.

Comment: technically, yes.  However, some browsers may treat `window` as implicit when not running code in strict mode.  See @Shusl's answer for a jsfiddle example.

Comment: Interesting. When trying that from console, it doesn't work in my chrome. In jsfiddle, on the other hand, it does, meaning it isn't running in exactly same context. Seems like relying on implicit context makes things very fragile and is probably to be avoided.

Comment: Yes, Chrome's console and most other consoles are a very fancy `eval`, which changes a lot of rules :-) See kangax's [*Understanding Delete*](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete) article for more info on `eval` and `delete`.  As an amendment to my earlier statement, it appears most browsers do allow deleting normal variables and not just where `window` would be implicit.  Strict mode, however, will throw an error.

Comment: Interesting again ;-). But, it seems, the OP has one of those browsers that object to this treatment. Hell, you do know a thing or two, you should've braindumped into the answer of your own. I'm not master of javascript, just answered, because there were no other answers :)

Comment: @AndyE: Slightly wrong: global variables declared with `var` are not deletable from the global object (per spec, at least: I think old IE gets this wrong). The kangax article has the details.

Comment: @Tim: yes, you're right.  It's the old IE behaviour that confused me here, since I used to write code for it exclusively (it's also a while since I read kangax's article!).

Answer (score 1):

First off, that's not how delete is supposed to be used. You can use it to delete properties from an object, so in your case you should write `delete window.MyDate`

Why should it be `undefined`? You remove the variable, thus you get

> Error: ReferenceError: MyDate is not defined