# How to correctly dereference then delete a JavaScript Object?

Tags: javascript, object, memory-management, garbage-collection, dereference

I would like to know the correct way to completely dereference a JavaScript Object from memory. To ensure it's deletion without it dangling in memory, and that the garbage collector removes the object.

When I looked and this question [Deleting Objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742623/deleting-objects-in-javascript1). It was explained that if you delete all the references of object, the GC will remove it from memory. I want to know how do I go about removing references from an object that has both methods and properties.

Suppose you have and object that was created by using `function`, and the object has both methods and properties. Say it looks something like this:

```
function myObject(x, y) {
   this.x = x; 
   this.y = y;

   this.myMethod = function() {
      // method code
   }
}

var myInstance = new myObject(24, 42) // How to remove this completely?
```

*Note*: This is an example, I understand you can use `prototype` for methods.

I know I can't just say `delete myInstance`. So in this case to completely delete the object will I need to call `delete` on all it's properties, and then call `delete` on the instance, like so?

```
delete myInstance.x;
delete myInstance.y;
delete myInstance; // I'm not sure if this is necessary.
```

Would this work? Or do I need to also `delete` it's methods (and if so how)?

Or perhaps there is a better and simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Javascript is a garbage collected language.  It will clean up an object ONLY when there is no other code that has a reference to it.  Those other references need to either go out of scope (and not be held by a closure) or you can set those other variables to something else so they don't point at your object.  When there are no other variables with a reference to your object, it will be automatically taken care of by the garbage collector, including any properties it has (assuming none of those properties are themselves objects that something has a reference to - but even then the host object would be cleaned up and only the object in the property would continue to live on).

You cannot delete an object any other way in Javascript.

So, to remove the object created by this:

```
var myInstance = new myObject(24, 42) // How to remove this completely?
```

Just clear `myInstance` like this:

```
myInstance = null;
```

You don't need to manually `delete` the properties from `myInstance` at all.  If nobody has a reference to the mother object and none of the properties are objects that someone has a reference to, then the garbage collector will just clean everything up for you.

The `delete` operator is primarily for removing properties from an object when you want the mother object to remain (e.g. when you just want to remove a property).

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I have a quick sub-question. If my object was in an array, should I first set it to `null`, then remove it from the array (with `splice()` for example)?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek - You do not need to first set it to `null` - that is just useless code.  If you're trying to remove a reference held in an array element, you can just use `.splice()` to remove that array element.  That will remove the reference to the object that was in the array and thus you've done all the GC needs.  If you wanted the array element to remain in your array, but wanted to clear the reference to the object, then you could just set that array element to `null`, but wouldn't need to use `.splice()` because you're leaving the array element in place.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've always used `.splice()` before and have been skeptical on whether the GC is getting everything (I'm removing/adding a large amount of objects in my current project, so I wanted to make sure). Thank you for clarifying that.