# Deleting an object in a for loop

Tags: javascript

When you're iterating over a javascript array using forEach, the object (obj in the example below) can be modified, and it will alter the original object in the array.

But if you delete it, why doesn't it remove it from the array? The following code doesn't appear to modify the array at all.

```
var myArr = [{test: 1},{test2: 2}];
console.log("before", myArr);
myArr.forEach(function(obj) {
   delete obj;
});
console.log("after", myArr);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deleting Objects in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742623/deleting-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: Just a suggestion: Just free yourself of all the hassle and use underscore or lodash which in this case you simply use the reject function for. lodash.com/docs (such an easy tool for working with objects and collections). Last thing you need in a large application is a 6 line ugly for loop for a remove method

Comment: @XGreen - library is a good option but fundamentals are more important.

Comment: can't argue with that

Comment: delete myArr[myArr.indexOf(obj)]; will delete the property - see my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`delete` removes properties, it doesn't destroy the value associated with a property.

`delete obj` is just trying (and failing) to remove the local variable `obj` from the current activation record.

It fails because an activation record, though it is an object, cannot have properties removed in this way.

One way to tell when a `delete` fails is to look at its return value, which is a boolean where true indicates that there is no such property/binding after the `delete` completes:

```
if (delete obj) {
  alert('the obj property was deleted');
} else {
  alert('delete did nothing');
}
```

Put that inside `(function () { var obj; ... })()` and it will tell you that it did nothing.

Put that inside `with ({ obj: null }) { ... }` and it will tell you that it worked.

In strict mode, any `delete` that would return false should instead raise an exception, and `delete`s that can never work should result in a parse-time error.

Comment: Relevant: http://es5.github.io/#x10.2.1.1.5. But I haven't found anything in the spec that explains when a binding is deletable. Do you have any info about that?

Comment: @FelixKling, quite right.  I thought that relates to the builtin *[[Configurable]]*.

Comment: @FelixKling, [#x11.4.1](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.1) has a non-normative note re *[[Configurable]]*

Comment: But only properties can be [[Configurable]]? Or am I wrong? I'm explicitly talking about bindings (of an environment record).

Comment: [The *DeleteBinding* Concrete method](http://es5.github.io/#x10.2.1.1.5) explains EnvironmentRecord binding deletion.

Comment: Yes, that's the link I posted in my first comment ;) And it says *"If the binding for N in envRec is cannot be deleted, return false."*. And my question was: "What makes a binding not deletable?"

Comment: @FelixKling, sorry, you're right.  I think [#10.5](http://es5.github.io/#x10.5) explains the conditions under which *configurableBindings* is true for a binding environment which affects the results of creation of bindings for that environment.

Comment: Ah thank you. I overlooked the part *"If D is true record that the newly created binding may be deleted by a subsequent DeleteBinding call."*  in http://es5.github.io/#x10.2.1.1.2. So it seems you can only delete bindings inside `eval` code. For whatever reasons :)

Comment: @FelixKling, and only if the `eval` operator appears lexically in a non-strict environment.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `delete` in this way. `delete` is for removing properties from objects.

You can do what you want by using [`splice`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp).

```
var myArr = [{test: 1},{test2: 2}];
console.log("before", myArr);
for (var i = 0, l = myArr.length; i < l; i++) {
  myArr.splice(i, 1);
  i--; l--;
}
console.log("after", myArr);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fh2fufae/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Delete does delete the property and for an array the property is its value. It works in this case. Array is a special type of object which has one more property called length. Array.length doesn't update unless you use splice or any array specific methods which modifies the value..

UPDATE: You could use the following to delete the value but array length will remain the same

```
var myArr = [{test: 1},{test2: 2}];
console.log("before", myArr);
myArr.forEach(function(obj) {
   delete myArr[myArr.indexOf(obj)];
});

console.log("after", myArr);
```

ALTERNATE:

```
var myArr = [{a:1},{a:2},{a:1}];
for(var i=0;i<myArr.length;i++){
  delete myArr[i];
}

console.log(myArr[1]); //undefined
```

Comment: Try `console.log(myArr.length);`. Using `delete` on an array doesn't usually produce the outcome you expect.

Comment: yea but that doesn't mean its not deleting the property value. Its just not releasing the memory

Comment: Oh no, it does both, but since it's a lower level operation, the array gets into a weird state. It doesn't change the size of the array. So if you have `var arr = [1,2,3];`, and do `delete arr[1];`, you end up with `[1,,3]`, not `[1,3]`. I'm just saying, while it removes the *property* it doesn't remove the *element* (from a higher level POV).

Comment: right and it doesn't update the length property of Array either

Answer (score 0):

@Andy's right, you want to use `splice` and not `delete` but a little trimmer version would simply be this:

```
var myArr = [{test: 1},{test2: 2}];
console.log("before", myArr);
for (var i = myArr.length; i > 0; i--) {
   myArr.splice(i--, myArr[i]);
}
console.log("after", myArr);
```