# Stop original Object reference from updating in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I have a object contains some companies name. when I am doing changes in `var m` which is copy of `var j` then `var j` is also updating. How can we prevent that

```
var j= {'a':'tata','b':'suzuki'}
var m= j
m.a='bmw'
console.log(m)
console.log(j)
```

Comment: Use delete operator. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742623/deleting-objects-in-javascript

Comment: @abhitalks—please, **any** answer but that one!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var j= {'a':'tata','b':'suzuki'}
var clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(j)); // or var clone = jQuery.extend({}, j);
//m.a='bmw'
clone.a = 'jaguar';
console.log(clone);
console.log(j);
```

Comment: That method of copying an object will not do a very good job of Types like Date.

Comment: You'd be better off using `_.extend` or `$.extend` (as in `clone = $.extend({}, j)`), or `Object.assign`, although that would give you a shallow copy.

Comment: @RobG agree with you