# Do I need to delete an object in javascript if I declared it with let?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In javascript if I declare an object with let, do I need to explicitly delete it?

Example:

```
downloadHelper(url) {
    let pom = document.createElement('a');
    pom.setAttribute('href', url);
    pom.setAttribute('download', '');
    pom.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(pom);
    pom.click();
    document.body.removeChild(pom);
    delete pom;
},
```

Comment: No you don't. Moreover, `delete` deletes object properties not variables.

Comment: [`delete` throws on variables](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/) declared with `let`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/let-keyword-vs-var-keyword) stackoverflow article may be of use. The short answer is no. Since the variable is still scoped to something, when that something gets deleted then the variable should get garbage collected, often sooner than a `var` as well.

Answer (score 2):

No you don't JavaScript is garbage collected. Delete only deletes the reference not actually object. Following explains all you needed.

Interesting Posts:
[Deleting Objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742623/deleting-objects-in-javascript)