# Delete JavaScript Object completely

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I am getting so many objects in a obj.Like this

```
Object {MAILING ADDRESS: "P O BOX 59", APN: "066-102-11-1"}
Object {MAILING ADDRESS: "", APN: ""}
Object {MAILING ADDRESS: "P O BOX 3", APN: "066-105-11-1"}
Object {MAILING ADDRESS: "", APN: ""}
```

When I apply a delete function on Null values of It I get this

```
Object {MAILING ADDRESS: "P O BOX 59", APN: "066-102-11-1"}
Object {}
Object {MAILING ADDRESS: "P O BOX 3", APN: "066-105-11-1"}
Object {}
```

I want to delete completely object{} and want to get only 2 Objects which have values. 
My code for deleting this values is

```js
(function filter(obj_field) {
  $.each(obj_field, function(key, value) {
    if (value === "" || value === null) {
      delete obj_field.key;
    } else if (Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === '[object Object]') {
      filter(value);
    } else if ($.isArray(value)) {
      $.each(value, function(k, v) {
        filter(v);
      });
    }
  });
})(obj_field);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742623/deleting-objects-in-javascript

Comment: I'm kinda sure you asked something like this earlier today. But again I'm gonna ask, can you please make a working example of your problem

Comment: `delete obj_field.key` - this deletes the key of the object. Use `delete obj_field` to get rid of the entire object.

Comment: If these are in an array there are much simpler ways to do this. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I get to know after 4 hours work that I need to loop through to delete obj . now I get the object Which I want to delete but Its deleting values not full object. returning  Object {} as I mentioned in question.

Comment: @TousifNoor You would help yourself if you created a working example of your code.

Comment: @J.Titus its doing nothing . returning first state.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I wish I could. I am working on part of project. Dont have access to database Just getting in this form data. And I have to do is delete object completely.

Comment: You're not returning anything. What do you mean it's "returning first state?" Please create a working example.

Comment: @J.Titus Its doing nothing. I mean giving result as it was.

Comment: You have the data and you have the code, it's poppycock that you can't create a working example. The data doesn't have to be everything, just a subset.

Comment: @George I think like this http://jsfiddle.net/DKBN6/16/

Comment: @TousifNoor Have you tried something simple like http://jsfiddle.net/ns3gtdng/ ?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen its returning empty arrays. I selected 12 items and got 12 empty arrays.

Comment: @TousifNoor Dude, I can't promise that it all works just by copy pasting my code into your project since you can't provide us with more information then its kinda hard to make your code work. you fiddle even have errors in the console.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Yes Now I get result but not in this format. simple 2 lines Malaing address and APN. how can I get in same formate like Array of object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets beautify the whole thing a bit:

```
mainObj={
 Object1: {"MAILING ADDRESS": "P O BOX 59", APN: "066-102-11-1"},
 Object2: {"MAILING ADDRESS": "", APN: ""},
 Object3: {"MAILING ADDRESS": "P O BOX 3", APN: "066-105-11-1"},
 Object4: {"MAILING ADDRESS": "", APN: ""} 
};

for(key in mainObj){
  if(!Object.values(mainObj[key]).some(el=>el)){
     delete mainObj[key];
  }
}
```

This will create this:

```
mainObj={
  Object1,Object3
};
```

http://jsbin.com/qazepupupi/edit?console

*Note: this ES6, you may use the code below if this code runs on old clientside browsers:*

```
for(key in mainObj){
  if(!Object.keys(mainObj[key]).some(function(inlinekey){ return mainObj[key][inlinekey]})){
     delete mainObj[key];
  }
}
```

Comment: I think I am using older version getting error on this.  '=>'.

Comment: still getting  Object {}  as output.

Comment: @TousifNoor not because of my code. Theres something else going wrong. My code is doing fine ( have a look at the jsbin)

Comment: @TousifNoor or the version for older browsers: http://jsbin.com/nuqijeciyu/edit?console

Answer (score 0):

```
 (function filter(obj_field) {
   $.each(obj_field, function(key, value) {
     if(isEmpty(value)) {
      delete obj_field.key;
     } else if (Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === '[object Object]') 
     {
        filter(value);
     } else if ($.isArray(value)) {
          $.each(value, function(k, v) {
           filter(v);
      });
        }
       });
   })(obj_field);

   function isEmpty(obj) {
      for(var key in obj) {
         if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
             return false;
      }
     return true;
     }
```

Comment: filter function will trigger itself ?  and isEmpty function I need to call that myself?

Comment: Maybe you can add an explanation to your answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `delete` operator deletes only a reference, it will not delete the object itself.

```
var myObj = {}
myObj.x = 30;

console.log(myObj.x); // '30'

delete myObj; // It will not delete the object
console.log(myObj.x); // '30'

delete myObj.x; // it will delete the property of the object 
console.log(myObj.x); // 'undefined'
```

Comment: It mean I cant delete Object ? @Rahul Kumar ?

Comment: @TousifNoor --  No, you can't delete the object. Please check this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Comment: then What should I do ? I am thinking of copy all object into array with a check of not null

Comment: you can try this one to check the objects without property.

function isEmpty(map) {
   for(var key in map) {
      return !map.hasOwnProperty(key);
   }
   return true;
}

Comment: @Jonasw How I can put If condition as If I do  if(value)  then I should not get that obj but still I am getting this .