# How to delete or filter a specific object inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, filter

Someone could help me with this problem? I have an `object/array` where I put an object with `"status = true"` after a specific condition. Now, my problem is, when all children objects are true, I would like to delete these objects and the parent. I will give an example of this issue.

```js
function removeProp(obj, propToDelete,value) {
    for (var property in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                if (typeof obj[property] == "object") {
                    removeProp(obj[property],propToDelete,value);
                } else {
                if(property === propToDelete && obj[property] == value){
                    delete obj[property];
                    //delete obj;
                    }
                }
            }
     }
}

var obj = 
{
    "name":"Bank Branch 1",
    "requests":[
       {
          "date":"2019-10-16 03:18:02",
          "req":[
             {
                "amount":"300",
                "coin":2
             },
             {
                "amount":"500",
                "coin":5
             }
          ]
       },
       {
          "date":"2019-10-16 03:19:05",
          "req":[
             {
                "amount":"300",
                "coin":2,
                "status":true
             },
             {
                "amount":"500",
                "coin":5
             }
          ]
       },
       {
          "date":"2019-10-16 03:19:20",
          "req":[
             {
                "amount":"22",
                "coin":2,
                "status":true
             },
             {
                "amount":"111",
                "coin":5,
                "status":true
             }
          ]
       }
    ]
 }
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
removeProp(obj,"status",true);
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

I expect this one, where I have to remove all objects where the status was true, and the parent "date" too. Look for the "2019-10-16 03:19:05", I don't want to remove it because there is an object that there is no  "status true" yet...  And "2019-10-16 03:19:20" was removed because all objects were true.

```js
var obj = 
{
    "name":"Bank Branch 1",
    "requests":[
       {
          "date":"2019-10-16 03:18:02",
          "req":[
             {
                "amount":"300",
                "coin":2
             },
             {
                "amount":"500",
                "coin":5
             }
          ]
       },
       {
          "date":"2019-10-16 03:19:05",
          "req":[
             {
                "amount":"300",
                "coin":2,
                "status":true
             },
             {
                "amount":"500",
                "coin":5
             }
          ]
       }
    ]
 }
```

Comment: You need 2 loops here, 1 for looping the `obj.requests` array, and then another to loop the `req` array inside these.

Answer (score 6):

You can filter the results into another array using [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) like this -

```
var result = obj.requests.filter(x => !x.req.every(y => y.status));
```

Run the snippet below to check results in the console.

```js
var obj = 
{
    "name":"Bank Branch 1",
    "requests":[
       {
          "date":"2019-10-16 03:18:02",
          "req":[
             {
                "amount":"300",
                "coin":2
             },
             {
                "amount":"500",
                "coin":5
             }
          ]
       },
       {
          "date":"2019-10-16 03:19:05",
          "req":[
             {
                "amount":"300",
                "coin":2,
                "status":true
             },
             {
                "amount":"500",
                "coin":5
             }
          ]
       },
       {
          "date":"2019-10-16 03:19:20",
          "req":[
             {
                "amount":"22",
                "coin":2,
                "status":true
             },
             {
                "amount":"111",
                "coin":5,
                "status":true
             }
          ]
       }
    ]
 }

var result = obj.requests.filter(x => !x.req.every(y => y.status));

console.log(result);
```

And then simply replace the `requests` property with the newly created array.

```
obj.requests = result;
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! 100%

Answer (score 2):

It's common nowadays when dealing with object & arrays to not mutate them.  Things like React etc, work better when you do this.  If this is the case @Vandesh answer is what you want.

On the other hand, if you still want to mutate your obj, you can do it like this ->

```js
var obj = {"name":"Bank Branch 1","requests":[{"date":"2019-10-16 03:18:02","req":[{"amount":"300","coin":2},{"amount":"500","coin":5}]},{"date":"2019-10-16 03:19:05","req":[{"amount":"300","coin":2,"status":true},{"amount":"500","coin":5}]},{"date":"2019-10-16 03:19:20","req":[{"amount":"22","coin":2,"status":true},{"amount":"111","coin":5,"status":true}]}]};

obj.requests.forEach((f, ix) => {
  if (f.req.every(x => x.status)) 
    obj.requests.splice(ix, 1);
});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks to be going in the right direction. If you want to delete the object itself, it would be done using "delete object" and would be placed outside the loop (keep in mind the scope here since you are passing obj to the function). However, delete operator deletes only a reference and not the object itself. Here is the link for the doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Also found a similar link on another post: [Deleting Objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742623/deleting-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: thanks for your support!