# How can I delete an object in Javascript/p5.js?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Basically I appended an object to a list every time it is created, and I have a loop that goes over this list and I want it to call the object's delete function as well as remove it from the list if this object fulfills some conditions.

I have tried adding this function into the object but calling it doesn't seem to change the length of the list.

```
    this.pop = function()
    {
        delete(this);
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include more code with expected input and output so that we may reproduce your issue.

Comment: [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) is unlikely to be the operator you want. If you have an array, [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) is a method of interest. But there are questions galore on Stack Overflow about how to [remove items from arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5767325), [properties from objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/208105), and [objects from existence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/742623)

Answer (score 0):

The `delete` operator is not a function and is used to remove properties from Objects ([Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete))

It's not super clear what you're trying to do exactly, but you have a couple options for removing an Object from an Array.

- [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)
- [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)
- [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Hope this points you in the right direction! :)