# Delete property from shallow copied object

Tags: javascript, shallow-copy

If I have one object, and shallow copy of it. For example:

```js
var person = {
  name: "Foo",
  age: 10,
  child: {
    name: "Matrix"
  }
}

var copiedPerson = {...person}
console.log(person, copiedPerson);
```

If I change `person.name = "NewName";`, copedPerson will stay intact.

If I change `person.age = 8;`, copiedPerson will stay intact.

But if I change `person.child.name = "Neo";`, `copiedPerson.name` will also through reference to point also to same name "Neo".

Everything about that is clear to me.

But I do not understand, why when I `delete person.child;`, nothing happens to `copiedPerson.child;`

In my logic cause both of them changes when I change one of them, now I also expected when one of them is deleted that other one should also be deleted. (Cause they references to same location in memory)

Can someone explain me why this didn't happen and which part I misunderstood?

Comment: Have a look at [Deleting Objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/742623/1048572)

Comment: Try to assign `person.child` to `null` and see if `copiedPerson.child` is also updated to `null` or not. I think that will help you understand this better.

Answer (score 1):

There is a little gap in the mental model you're having about the references right now. So essentially, you understand that if you change the nested object `person.child.name` the value in the `copiedPerson.child.name` would change too.

But at the end of the day, the `child` property is only containing the **reference** of the nested object for both `person` and the `copiedPerson` objects.

So, when you delete it from the original `person` object, you're deleting the **reference** of this nested object from the person's child property but this nested object still remains in the memory

Hence, the reference contained in the `copiedPerson.child` still remains untouched and can access this object saved in the memory

Comment: If I understood correctly, I have `person.child.name` which reference into memory location for example `1001`, and also have `copiedPerson.child.name` which also reference into memory location `1001`. And in memory location `1001` I have value `Matrix`. And when I `delete person.child.name` I only delete one reference to that memory location, but another one (copiedPerson.child.name) reference to location `1001` still stay intact.

Answer (score 0):

`delete` [does not destroy the object](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete) that is referenced by a variable or property.

`delete` removes a property from an object - in your case the `person` object - just like an assignment adds it.

Comment: can you read my comment on d_bhatnagar answer to check if my process of thinking now correct, I didn't read your article yet, but I will do it in few minutes.

Comment: @PredragDavidovic That comment is about `delete person.child.name`, not about `delete person.child` as in your question. Deleting the `.name` property from the object that is referenced from both `person.child` and `copiedPerson.child` is the same as `person.child.name = "Neo";` about modifying that child object, not modifying either of the persons.

Comment: You have right, I understood it in wrong way.  As you said whan I do `delete person.child.name` it also deleted it from `copied.person.name`.

I got it all wrong :(

Answer (score -1):

it is cause the different variables specify on the same object. You should clone obj by `cloneObj` function

```js
function cloneObj(obj) {
  var res = {};
  for (var i in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[i] == "object") {
      res[i] = cloneObj(obj[i]);
    } else {
      res[i] = obj[i];
    }
  }
  
  return res;
}

var person = {
  name: "Foo",
  age: 10,
  child: {
    name: "Matrix"
  }
}

var copiedPerson = cloneObj(person);

copiedPerson.child.name = "Neo";

console.log(person);
console.log(copiedPerson);
```

Comment: I don't think this helps explain things (the code seems fine though)

Comment: its definitely solved this problem `But if I change person.child.name = "Neo";, copiedPerson.name will also through reference to point also to same name "Neo".`

Comment: @Fakt309 That's not a problem. "*Everything about that is clear to me.*"