# Does reinitializing class instance cause garbage collection?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a project in which multiple classes are being utilized and I want to make sure that no excessive garbage memory is being collected

now from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/742666/15573857) answer, it says

> Since Javascript is garbage collected, you don't need to delete
> objects themselves - they will be removed when there is no way to
> refer to them anymore.

I've written a pseudo code which resembles my problem

```js
class person{
 constructor(name){
  this.name=name;
 }
 
 work(){
  //does work
 }
};

while(true){
 let someone= new person(variable_name);
 someone.work();
}
```

I know the example is a bit vague but what I want to know is that since we're reinitializing `someone` again and again does it accumulate junk data? or since it loses reference, the previous ones are being deleted?

I want to make sure this doesn't have a long time memory junk issue with heavier projects

Comment: The code as written will probably be garbage-collected just fine, as `someone` is block-scoped and there does not appear to be any other references to the object.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol despite multiple looping right?

Comment: What doesk `work()` do?

Comment: @programmerRaj it's just a sample method to show that the class instance is being used

Comment: Then I agree with @NiettheDarkAbsol. The example won't cause any memory leaks.