# How to remove Model-Markers in MonacoEditor

Tags: monaco-editor, ngx-monaco-editor

Currently, I'm trying to remove model-markers from a Monaco-Model with the following approach.

```
    monac.editor.getModelMarkers({owner: "owner"}).forEach(marker => {
      console.log(marker)
      marker.dispose()
    })
```

Markers currently are set through the setModelMarker() method

```
monaco.editor.setModelMarkers(editor.getModel(), "owner", markers)
```

Setting an empty array to the Model override the model-markers, so this could be used as a workaround.

```
monaco.editor.setModelMarkers(editor.getModel(), "owner", [])
```

Is there any way how I could reliably remove model-markers

Comment: Doesn't this last solution work?
Setting markers as an empty array is the way to remove model markers in monaco editor.

Comment: yes it does, but shouldn't the dispose function also somewhat work ? Otherwise I compute the array of markers I want to keep externally and override all of them which seems to be kind of redundant to me

Comment: Actually, no, it shouldn't even execute. [According to API specification](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/modules/monaco.editor.html#getModelMarkers), `getModelMarkers()` returns an array of [IMarker](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.IMarker.html), which do not have a `dispose()` method.
`setModelMarkers` really is the preferred way for any markers set modification, including deletion.

Comment: @AstorBizard Great thanks fo the insides, im going to write an summary answer on the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, `getModelMarkers()` returns an array of [IMarker](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.IMarker.html), which do not have a `dispose()` method.
For any modification of the marker set, `setModelMarkers()` is the way.
The main explanation is that `IMarker`s are just interface object, which must thus have fields like `severity`, `startLineNumber`, etc.
The Monaco editor uses a single `setModelMarkers()` method to update the marker set, as any modification of these objects after calling the method will have no effect:

```js
var markers = [{
    severity: monaco.MarkerSeverity.Warning,
    message: "Some warning",
    startLineNumber: 1,
    startColumn: 1,
    endLineNumber: 1,
    endColumn: editor.getModel().getLineLength(1) + 1
}];
monaco.editor.setModelMarkers(editor.getModel(), "owner", markers);
markers[0].severity = monaco.MarkerSeverity.Error; // No effect
```

With the same idea, you cannot delete a marker (with `delete markers[0];` for example), as [the delete operator deletes only a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742623/deleting-objects-in-javascript/742666#742666).

Comment: good one :D thanks for the summary