How to delete an Object in JS?
I have some monsters writed in my code, and I would like to delete them at the moment they die. Their image, HP, attackPower ect.. So they don't appear anymore nor deal damage. However, I don't really know how to.
I've tried to nullify them, this isn't working. Same for Delete (I am struggling hard). So do I have to make an array of monsters ? Here is my code :
Class Person

  attack(target){    
    while (this.sprite.animationFrameProgress === 8 ){
      this.sprite.animationFrameProgress -= 0.5;
    }
    if (this.sprite.animationFrameProgress === 0){
      target.health -= this.attackPower;
    }
    if (target.health <= 0){
      delete target.???;
    }
    console.log(target.health);
  }

Class OverworldMap

playerAttackNearestMonster() {
    const player = this.gameObjects.hero;
    for (const key in this.gameObjects) {
      if (key !== 'hero' && this.gameObjects.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        const monster = this.gameObjects[key];
        const distanceX = Math.abs(monster.x - player.x);
        const distanceY = Math.abs(monster.y - player.y);
        if (distanceX <= 16 && distanceY <= 16) {
          monster.sprite.setAnimation("fighting");
          monster.attack(player);
          if (player.attacking){
            player.attack(monster);
          }
         
        }
      }
    }

slime: new Monster({
        x: utils.withGrid(7),
        y: utils.withGrid(8),
        pixelSize: 32,
        health : 50,
        attackPower : 15,
        animations : {
          "monster" : [[0,0], [1,0],[2,0], [3,0]],
          "monster-left" : [[0,5], [1,5],[2,5], [3,5]],
          "monsterWalk-down" : [[0,1], [1,1],[2,1], [3,1],[4,1], [5,1]],
          "monsterWalk-up" : [[0,1], [1,1],[2,1], [3,1],[4,1], [5,1]],
          "monsterWalk-right" : [[0,1], [1,1],[2,1], [3,1],[4,1], [5,1]],
          "monsterWalk-left" : [[0,6], [1,6],[2,6], [3,6],[4,6], [5,6]],
      },
        src: "/images/characters/monsters/slime.png"
      }),



Might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742623/deleting-objects-in-javascript

The name playerAttackNearestMonster suggests that only one monster will be attacked, the nearest one. But this is not always going to happen. That loop may call attack multiple times. Is this what you intend to happen?

You mean the attack will be call not only once for 2 monsters or sum but like 2 times ect ?

Move your object deletion out of attack into playerAttackNearestMonster:
player.attack(monster);

if (monster.health <= 0) {
    delete this.gameObjects[key]
}



I've found a solution thanks to Justinas. Here is it :

    removeGameObject(gameObject) {
      for (const key in this.gameObjects) { 
        if (this.gameObjects[key] === gameObject) {
          delete this.gameObjects[key]; // delete the object
          console.log(`Object ${key} removed from the game.`);
          return;
        }
      }

